# Can we access the secured coap url through copper plugin in Firefox?

Tags: coap

I am just wondering if we can access the DTLS enabled COAP urls through the copper plugin.
I am able to access

> coap:\localhost:5683

How can we access

> coaps:\localhost:5683

after enabling DTLS, through copper plugin in the Firefox browser?

Answer (score 0):

I've found nothing regarding DTLS in the Copper code
https://github.com/mkovatsc/Copper

So unfortunately the answer is - we can not.